# Jest unit test case for componentDidMount const ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, babel-jest

I have `componentDidMount` which have one const. I am trying to cover unit test case for const which have ternary operator. Can anyone please help me on this how to cover ternary operator condition.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const learnerId = (this.props.routeParam) ?
            this.props.routeParam.learnerId :
            MaterialModuleList.getQueryString('learnerId');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Enzyme with Jest to write tests. If you aren't already, checkout Enzyme.

You need two cases to achieve 100% coverage. First, mount the component the component with the routeParam, Second, mount the component by setting routeParam to false. Alternatively, you can use the setProps method (from enzyme) for the latter case.

```
component.setProps({
    routeParam: false
});
```

Here, for the latter case, you can `MaterialModuleList.getQueryString` method to assert whether it was called.

For the first case however, you CANNOT write an assertion(The test will achieve 100% coverage though). To write an assertion, you should either return the const, or set it to some global variable, which you have access to.